# rxjs 6 countdown timer subscribe angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, countdowntimer

I try to implement a countdown timer in angular 6 using rxjs 6. I also need to be able to subscribe to results and to reset the timer:

What I tried:

```
var timer =  interval(1000).pipe(
take(4)
);
timer.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Result:

```
0
1
2
3
```

What I need is to reverse the timer to count from 3 to 1

I found this coundown function to implement reverse count, but I cannot subscribe to it, like in first example

```
 interval(1000).pipe(
 map((x) => { console.log( x) })
  );
```

Result:

empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use timer instead of interval, to actually implement the countdown you should map the timer result like this: `map(i => countdownStart - i)`

```
  const countdownStart = 3;

  Rx.Observable
    .timer(1000, 1000)
    .map(i =>  countdownStart - i)
    .take(countdownStart + 1)
    .subscribe(i => console.log(i));
```

Logs:
3
2
1
0

Another possible solution is to use the range operator.

```
Rx.Observable
  .range(0, countdownStart + 1)
  .map(i => countdownStart - i)
  .subscribe(i => console.log(i));
```

Logs:
3
2
1
0

Comment: thanks for answer, but I still struggle to implement this in rxJs 6, this sintax I get errors

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it with `TimerObservable`. Remember to unsubscribe on destroy.

```
import {TimerObservable} from "rxjs/observable/TimerObservable";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private sub: Subscription;

    ngOnInit() {
        // Delay 0 seconds, run every second
        let timer = TimerObservable.create(0, 1000);

        let number = 3;

        this.sub = timer.subscribe(t => {
            if(number !== 0) {
               console.log(number);
               number--;
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
var timer =  interval(1000).pipe(
  take(4),
  map(x => 3 - x)
);
timer.subscribe(console.log);
```